# Implement Horizontal Date Picker in Android

Tags: android, datepicker, horizontal-scrolling

I have a requirement to implement a horizontal date picker as shown in below image:

[image: plz click here to see image]

I have tried lots of libraries and googled it about for three days.

I customized [this library](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel) but not able to style the selected item. i.e. Different color and size.

Please let me know, If is there any suggestion or sample code which can help me to implement the similar requirement.

Comment: try https://github.com/asantibanez/Ranger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HorizontalPicker is a custom-build Android View used for choosing dates (similar to the native date picker) but draws horizontally into a vertically narrow container. It allows easy day picking using the horizontal pan gesture.

resource :

- https://github.com/jhonnyx2012/HorizontalPicker
- https://github.com/GastricSpark/ScrollDatePicker

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved my problem with customizing recyclerview. but your mentioned libraries are so good!

Comment: Welcome happy to help :)